# Probability of rolling to dice

Tags: probability

If 2 fair dice are rolled together , what is the probability that the sum will be 9

1)Is the probability 4/36 (1/9); as no. of favorable cases are {(3,6);(6,3);(4,5);(5,4)} ?

2) Or is it 2/36 (1/18); as no. of favorable cases are {(3,6);(4,5)}
the reason I am confused  is that the question does not state if the dices are distinguishable or not.
If they are not distinguishable then the answer should be 1/18 as stated in case 2. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Hint: in scenario 2, are there really 36 different cases in total?

Comment: Even if the dice are **NOT** distinguishable, the probability of $(4,5)$ is $\frac{2}{36}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dice are not distinguishable then the total number of outcomes is only 21 (15 where they are different and 6 where they are equal) and even those 21 do not all have equal probability (the 6 have each only half the likelihood of the 15). So by a detour we also arrive at 1/9 if they are indistinguishable.